# Tomcat server crashing

Tags: tomcat, sbt

> SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_init]) for component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]] in state [INITIALIZED]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:402)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:343)
>           at webapp.runner.launch.Main.main(Main.java:275)

Comment: Is something missing in the configuration?

Comment: You may have another instance of Tomcat already running and using port 8080. What have you changed to end up with this error? have you upgraded tomcat?

Comment: I tried upgrading tomcat

Comment: 1- If it is possible reboot your machine to be sure that there's no other instance running

Comment: I tried rebooting but does not work

Comment: Have you brought any jar file from your old tomcat to the new one? or if you deployed an application on your new tomcat does that uses any jar files from the old tomcat. what version you using now

Comment: I am using 7.0.75 and there are no jars from the previous tomcat

Comment: There might be another application or server that is using port 8080. 
as a final test could you try to change the port that Tomcat is using in server.xml

Comment: having said that you should see something like java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [98] Address already in use, if the port is the issue. if you still got your old tomcat check what port that was running on.

Comment: You'll need to provide the code you use to configure and start the instance of the Tomcat class.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the sbt embedded Tomcat (jsimone webapp-runner) and had the same error. The error disappeared when I upgraded to 8.5.11.0 so I assumed [this](https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner/commit/e329fb7ac3023b8de9da720a21d0e7a8ba84e307#diff-da096e5f9b2a6f139fef5e02984bc9a5) fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I used apache-tomcat-8.5.23, and when I created project instances with idea, I didn't delete the projects under the original tomcat, which led to the fact that the project instances could not be deployed, and OK was deleted.